# How to translate a custom module template file?

Tags: i18n-l10n

How do I translate a custom module theme file?

```
function bonds_graph_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)
{
    $items = array();

    $items[BONDS_GRAPH_MODULE_NAME] = array(
   'arguments' => array(),
   'file' => 'inc/theme.inc',
   'template' => 'tpl/bonds_graph',
 );

return $items;
}
```

The theme file has a translatable string

```
<?php print date('Y') . ' ' . t('Issuance'); ?>
```

The language file zh-hans.po has the translation

```
#: tpl/bonds_graph.tpl.php:7
msgid "Issuance"
msgstr "发行"
```

The site language is set. How do I get the string translated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .po file must be located in `custom_module/translations` directory - see [locale_batch_by_component](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21locale.inc/function/locale_batch_by_component/7.x) function. Translation file though is only imported once module gets installed, so in case you want to reimport the file you would have to run some "hacky" drush command, such as `drush php-eval "locale_system_update(array('custom_module'));drush_backend_batch_process();"`

You can also upload .po file manually using Drupal's admin UI.